# Loading client's images into a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been searching this website for answers to this question, but I couldn't seem to find any. So I want to have the client provide an image to be loaded into a canvas for processing **and that's it**. So I don't want to save it on the server or on a cloud, but I just want to copy the image to an HTML5 Canvas to be processed from there. Is there a way I can do that without actually saving the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. You want that the user can open an image from the client and you load it into a html5 canvas. correct?

If so: you can use an input field of type file. In your code you use URL.createObjectUrl to create object urls from the local selected images. With "Image" you can load the image and in the onload event you draw it to the canvas.

```
 var file = document.getElementById('file'); // the input element of type file
 file.onchange = function(e) {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'); // load context of canvas
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]); // use first selected image from input element
   img.onload = function() {
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // draw the image to the canvas
   }
 }
```

Comment: If you have any problems take a look to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xd89skb/ or ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: Looks good...upvote. :-) One useful point is that the user can put in an `http://` url to an image and that web image will be pulled into the user's local cache and drawn from there onto the canvas using your code.

Comment: I would say it's a feature not a bug ;) But you are right. I upvoted your post. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @JoshuaK. Yes, I definitely didn't mean to imply `http://` access was a bug--it's definitely a feature! :-) For the longest time we've been wanting the browsers to allow users to load (even internet) image files without tainting the canvas because of cross-domain security restrictions. It's good to know the browsers have (finally!) given us this path. Cheers!