# what is the solution to HTML5's Filereader stucking images

Tags: javascript, html, image, file-upload, filereader

i'm going to start with showing you guys the code:

```
var oFile = $('#attached-file')[0].files[0];
var oImage = document.getElementById('UserImg');
        var oReader = new FileReader();
        oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
        oReader.onload = function (e) {
            oImage.src = e.target.result;
            oImage.onload = function () {

                    $('#UserImg').show();
                    $('#UserImg').Jcrop({
                        onChange: updateInfo,
                        onSelect: updateInfo,
                        minSize: [150, 160],
                        setSelect: [150, 160, 50, 50]
                    });
            }
        }
```

The problem is that if I upload more than one image with the FileUploader (#attached-file) the old ones stay and i get multiple images at the same time.
So haw can I reset the img clear before I load a new iamge to it? 
Thank you

Comment: use a canvas instead of an image or set the image src to undefined. should work both. but first solution is the prefered one today. canvas and then draw on it.

Comment: sorry but i dont know what is the canvas and setting the image src to "" or to "#" didnt help

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869471/loading-clients-images-into-a-canvas/31869576#31869576